# Custom errors in apache config files (not error pages)

Tags: apache

I'm not looking to create custom error pages, but to actually issue error messages when the config file is parsed. Specifically, I want to use an `<IfModule>` to throw up an error if the module hasn't been loaded, so it's easier to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the only kludgy thing I could think of (and requires mod_rewrite enabled):

```
<IfModule !mod_deflate.c>
        ErrorDocument 500 "mod_deflate isn't available"
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteRule .* - [R=500]
</IfModule>
```

If you find a better way to 'trigger' errors, I'm certainly interested ;)

Comment: Clever idea. Definitely not what I was looking for, but it would pretty much work. Still looking for better solutions if anyone else has them.

Answer (score 1):

For Httpd 2.4 see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/core.html#error

For older versions

```
<IfModule !mod_deflate.c>
     Mod_deflate_not_enabled.
</IfModule>
```

will raise something like

```
Syntax error on line 7 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:
Invalid command 'Mod_deflate_not_enabled.', perhaps misspelled ...
   ...fail!
```

when you reload the server config.